# Opening port in iptables doesn't work

Tags: linux, iptables

I add the following line before COMMIT in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Then I use `service iptables restart` to restart `iptables`, but the port is still closed - if I stop iptables `service iptables stop`, the port is opened.

`iptables -L -n`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `iptables -L -n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking in `iptables` terms the order is **very** important:

```
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80
```

So you firstly reject anything that hasn't matched any previous rule, and *then* you accept port 80. That's why this rule won't ever be triggered. Try using -I instead of -A.

Comment: Or change the policy to Reject and remove the REJECT rule

Answer (score 0):

Brother use CLI as below. from the location of the file it seems like you are on CentOS or Redhat.

> iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j
>   ACCEPT

This will put this rule on top.  After this save it as below.

> service iptables save

You don't need to restart the service it will take effect immediately.  I can see from your post that you appended rule for accepting on port 80 is behind the Reject rule. The solution I proposed will fix it.

Comment: I went ahead and provided formatting and fixed the grammar in this answer.  I suggest you pay more attention to the small details so you can post excellent answers instead of just below average answers.